# Cannot download and install my crx chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, hosting

I've created a little chrome extension and I put the crx file into my web space but when I try to download and install it I get this error: "Apps must be served with content type application/x-chrome-extension.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this link - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html - , you have to edit the `.htaccess` file in your server. In particular, you have to add the following line:

```
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, however I added the line to .htaccess, even tried to add to main config file, but still no luck. It says it have to have that mime type. What might be the problem ?

Comment: Maybe that option is not supported from your server.

Comment: I can change anything, what should I do ?